# Very Basic Python 2.7.13 Trouble opening files in IDLE and python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

took a break from programming and am trying to get an old program up and running. I previously wrote a program called 'NetsimGUI' that uses modules networkx and matplotlib. I could not figure out how to install them on a new computer (running Windows 10) and then realized I could barely do anything at all. In the Python command window after importing pip I have tried the following:

```
'python pip install networkx'

'pip install networkx'

'python NetsimGUI'

'python NetsimGUI.py'

'Python NetsimGUI.py'

'Python27 NetsimGUI.py'

'NetsimGUI.py'

'NetsimGUI'

'python -m pip install -U pip'

'python -v'

'py27 -v'

'py -27 -v'

'Python -v'
```

and so on. All give errors saying NameError: name 'python' or name 'py' is not defined or something similar. PATH environment variable is set to C:\Python27 and NetsimGUI.py is in that folder as well. Guessing the solution is something super simple I am missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't import pip into python. Open Windows Command Prompt and do the pip installs there. Importing Python into Python is as though it were self-aware :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're basically having trouble installing pip on Windows. What you're doing isn't exactly correct, the correctly way to install pip 2.7 on Windows is detailed [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

From the docs:

> To install pip, securely download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).
>
> Then run the following:
>
> `python get-pip.py`

Once you've done that, you should be able to install python modules as normal.

Comment: Pip should come with Python 2.7 so this is weird

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No? I've never actually seen pip bundled with python2.7. That's only true of python 3+, unless the python2 package for windows is different in that regard?

Comment: It should for >= 2.7.9 https://docs.python.org/2.7/installing/#key-terms